# Why "inspect element" shows input element's width as 100% on hovering, but its actual width is less?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

The orange band on hovering on the input element extends to the full width of the screen. But the actual width of the element being shown in dev tools is just **169px**. If the orange band doesn't represent the width, then what does it represent?

If I hover on the label field, the orange width also takes the full width but the width that now gets shown in dev tools is **820px**. Why this disparity?

Note that I've assigned `display:block` to all `input` and `label` fields.

Comment: @GonzaloFS The only CSS in the code is: `label,input{
 display:block;  
}`

Comment: input has a default width so it's a block element taking its own row with a limited width. It's like setting width to a div

Comment: and the orange space is margin

Comment: @TemaniAfif Orange space is not margin. I haven't applied any margin.

Comment: you don't need to apply it, check the duplicate to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element itself is only so wide, but its rendering block is full-width (as indicated by the orange rectangle). The space occupied by the rendering block is essentially reserved. If you were to put another input *after* that one it would drop to a new line.

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" value="blocked!" style="display: block;" />
    <input type="text" value="dropped!" /> 
    <input type="text" value="not dropped!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, so strictly speaking, what does the orange band indicate? space reserved for that element, not the element's actual width, right?

Comment: It indicates the rendering block. Obviously the element is not full width.

Answer (score 2):

That is due to the input having `display: block` in the css:

> A block-level element always starts on a new line. A block-level element always takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).
>
> [Attribution](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp#:%7E:text=Block%2Dlevel%20Elements,an%20inline%20element%20does%20not.)

Changing the CSS to `display: inline-block` will not cause that.

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="block" placeholder="block"><span>more text</span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="inline-block" placeholder="inline-block"><span>more text</span>
<p>Use dev-tools to see the difference...
```

Comment: But the input element is showing a width of only 169px. Its not taking the full width available, even though the orange band takes the full width

Comment: I edited the snippet by placing a `<span>` to the right of each input. See how the block-level element forces the `<span>` to the next line.